# Swift : Transform SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, animation, skspritenode

Im trying to implement this code for a UIView but for a SKSprite Node:

```
stopIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.stopIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        })
```

My SKSprite Node is set up like this:

```
stopIcon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "StopIcon")
    stopIcon?.size = CGSize(width: ((stopImage?.size.width)! * 0.75), height: ((stopImage?.size.height)! * 0.75))
    stopIcon?.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.22, y: self.size.height * 0.91)
    self.addChild(stopIcon!)
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im guessing you would like to scale the SKSpriteNode over 0.5 seconds, from 0.1 -> 1.0 (a tenth of original scale to the full scale).

Using SpriteKit's SKAction class this can be implemented like so:

```
//set the inital scale of node to 0.1
stopIcon.setScale(0.1)
//create action to scale skspritenode to scale of 1.0 over 0.5 seconds.
let scaleAction = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.5)
//call on the action.
stopIcon.runAction(scaleAction)
```